# queue:listen timeout stop processing queue processing

Tags: php, laravel, timeout, queue, jobs

i'm using laravel 5 queue for render some 3d files with blender.

some models, have problem with rendering and rendering time is really high like 1 min.

i want to have timeout for doing job (60 sec), when i add timeout to queue:listen , if some job executing time be higher that 60 second , my queue stops but i want just ignore that job and continue doing other jobs.

command i ran:

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=60
```

error :

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]                                                                                                                     
  The process "'/usr/local/php56/bin/php56' 'artisan' queue:work '' --queue='default' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=120 --env='production'" exceeded the timeout of 60
  seconds.
```

what should i do for solving this ?

**Edit:**

I googled supervisor,and i found that supervisor is used to continue queue when any problem happened such rebooting VPS or other problem happening outside of job works.

I do n't think supervisor must be used for my problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use supervisor to restart the process again [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#supervisor-configuration). You can't really catch a PHP timeout. Set the tries to 1, so it doesn't attempt the large process.

Comment: thanks for fast responding.
is there any solution to do that in shared hosting ?

Comment: You could try using the database queue driver and using a cron job. I've never done it, but it may be worth a shot. Other than that, get yourself a VPS. It's pretty much the same price as shared hosting (see DigitalOcean or similar)

Comment: As long as you have access to SSH you should be able to follow the docs and get supervisor up and running. Good luck!

Comment: i thing supervisor is not good solution , each time i want change any setting i should login as root ....